# How to disable jquery validation when editing an invalid field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I use jQuery.validate.js. I have multiple validation on one text field in a registration form. The validations are (1) cannot be blank. (2) must be an email. (3) cannot be an email already registered.

If I enter an email already registered, the error message shows up as expected. Then I start to delete text in the field. The error message for 'must be an email' pops up. When all text in the field is deleted, the error message for 'cannot be blank' pops up. This did not happen when I first edited the field before it's invalid.

I don't want the error messages show up when I'm editing the field after it is invalid. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to validate when the user blur the current input field. $("input").blur(function(){
        // Some validation error
    });

Answer (score 0):

Does this code fix your problem?

```
$(".selector").validate({
  onkeyup: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that's because *HTML5* validation look for this Pattern:

```
[somthing]@[somthing]
```

and i think you should use novalidate attr in your form .
then try to use Email pattern like this:

```
pattern = " /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/ "
```

but its better for understanding if you put your code in Question.